# Why isn't my navbar text changing color with CSS?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

With the following HTML and CSS I can't seem to be able to change the text color of the hyperlinks in blue or purple? What am I missing?

```css
nav ul {
  /* Navbar unordered */
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #495e57;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li {
  /* Navbar ordered */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li:hover {
  /* Navbar on mouse hover */
  background-color: #1f2926;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have tried making using of !important to no avail. The only successful method I found is wrapping it in the HTML code itself as such:

`<li><a style="color: white" href="index.html">Home</a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the color to the `li` instead of `a`.

`a` element has a default color so you need to select it.

```
a { 
  color: white;
}
```

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #495e57;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #1f2926;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or on (`li`) hover :

```
nav li:hover a {    
  color: white;
}
```

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #495e57;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #1f2926;
}

nav li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise I was using the a tag!

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to have the `a` tag's `color` property set to `inherit`, so that it inherits the computed color of its parent `li` property:

```css
nav ul {
  /* Navbar unordered */
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #495e57;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li {
  /* Navbar ordered */
  /* set default color to blue, so that anchor tags inherit this */
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li:hover {
  /* Navbar on mouse hover */
  background-color: #1f2926;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  /* anchor tags should inherit color of parent */
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Useful indeed if there are more items in `li`